# Extract 15 words before and 8 words after each 9digit number from a text file using regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex

Extract 15 words before and 8 words after each 9digit number from a text file using regular expressions in python. It should list all string including overlap text.

I tried with some regular expressions but it doesn’t work for overlap text

Comment: What have you tried?  We aren't going to do your homework for you.

Comment: It's probably easier to **not** use regular expressions

Comment: ((?:\S+\s+){0,15}\b [0-9]{0,3}). This is fetching first 15 words before a 3 digit number, in case if there are multiple numbers then it skips the overlap extraction.

Comment: What if there are not 15 words before and 8 words after? How do you define a "word"? Have you thought this through?